# Converting tif files to pdf with python

Tags: python

Hi I have a folder with multiple .tif files that I'm trying to convert to individual pdf's. I'm trying to use python as they are more than 3000. I was able to convert a single one but when implementing a code I found for multiples is giving me an error "No such file or directory:" This is the code I'm using, thanks in advance.

```
from PIL import Image 
import os
directory = r'/Users/reynierDesktop/Drive/' 
for filename in os.listdir(directory): 
    if filename.endswith(".tif"): 
        prefix = filename.split(".tif")[0]
        im = Image.open(filename)
        im.save(prefix+'.pdf')  
    else: 
        continue
```

I was able to find something and it kind of works. It converts the tif files to pdf, but if the tiff files has more than 1 page it only converts the first one. Any idea how to go around this? Thanks.

```
from PIL import Image
import os

def makePdf(imageDir, SaveToDir):
    os.chdir(imageDir)
    for j in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
           os.chdir(imageDir)
           fname, fext= os.path.splitext(j)
           newfilename = fname + ".pdf"
           im = Image.open(fname + fext)
           os.chdir(SaveToDir)
           im.save(newfilename, "PDF", resolution = 100.0)


imageDir = r'my directory path'
SaveToDir = r'where to save them'
makePdf(imageDir, SaveToDir)
```

Comment: Python looks for the file in the current directory. Probably, you are running your script in a directory different than where your .tif files are located.
You need to replace `filename` with *file path*; i.e., `os.path.join(directory, filename)`

Comment: If you had try debugging by printing out what `filename` actually contains – the file to process –, you would have noticed that the path is missing. That is by design: you only get the file names you are asking for.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to Python, the files are in that folder. If I do individually like this it works:                                                                                                                      from PIL import Image
parent_folder = '/Users/reynier/Desktop/Drive/'
image = Image.open('/Users/reynier/Downloads/020694.tif')
image.save("out.pdf", save_all=True)

Answer (score 0):

jonathan,
your directory may be /Users/reynierDesktop/Drive/
but your filename is only something.tif
(you can see this if you print out the filename)

so when you Image.open(filename), you are looking for 
something.tif
not
/Users/reynierDesktop/Drive/something.tif

so one way around that would be to concat the directory with the filename when using Image.open or you could cd into /Users/reynierDesktop/Drive/ first and then just the filename will be found because you are in the correct directory.